# I want to load a template from the templates folder but I get an error that says the included URLconf does not appear to have any patterns in it

Tags: python, django

I am trying to load a template in my templates/pages folder and get the `error: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '<module 'pages.urls' from 'D:\\django\\pages\\pages\\urls.py'>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.`

I have tried putting the templates folder in both the project and the app directory but still get the same error.

In my settings.py I have:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

and:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'pages',
]
```

my urls.py file in the root project folder named pages_project looks like:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('pages.urls')),
]
```

and my urls.py in my app folder named pages looks like:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

path('', views.HomePageView.as_view(), name='home')
```

my views.py looks like:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name= 'home.html'
```

I have a template file named home.html in the path pages/templates/pages/home.html and looks like:

```
<h1>Homepage</h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with templates.

As the error says, the included URLconf doesn't have any patterns in it. As you can see from the main urls.py, you need to define a list named `urlpatterns` which contains your patterns. So your pages urls.py should be:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.HomePageView.as_view(), name='home')
]
```

Comment: I did as you said and the error is not there any more but now I get  TemplateDoesNotExist at / error

Comment: It should be `template_name= 'pages/home.html'`.